Can 'can' be used as a main verb?
One of my pupils wrote

"Having a skill means to CAN something ...".

This explanation would work perfectly well grammatically in German if you translate it literally.
Can you use this modal auxiliary without a main verb? I've never seen it (unless the sentence is elliptical).

This question was discussed here quite recently, though I haven’t found where. The answer is no.

@PaulTanenbaum: My first thought was You can look this up in a dictionary, so I initially voted to close. Then I changed my my and answered anyway, but your comment (which I saw after posting my answer) encourages me to think I made the right decision.

@ FumbleFingers: Please do share the dictionary with me that will answer that kind of question.

Does this answer your question? Using "can" as a regular verb: Unable to can

@ James K: Hi James, While it basically is the same topic, I  think both my question as well as the answer by Fumble Fingers is worth keeping. Neither Paul Tannenbaum nor I were able to find the topic the way it was originally worded. I hope this will help someone who's got the same question.

@grasshopper I would have written: "Neither Paul Tannenbaum nor I was able to find" in the singular.

@tchrist: Thanks for the hint, that's interesting. According to German native speaker logic: Paul + I = two people --> requires plural. Wrong in English?

@grasshopper It's not different. But you did ɴᴏᴛ use ᴀɴᴅ, which would indeed have produced a plural since it would have selected both. Instead you used ɴᴏʀ which being ɴᴏᴛ ᴏʀ is just like ᴏʀ ɴᴏᴛ and so selects for ᴏɴʟʏ ᴏɴᴇ of the two possible alternatives. Under disjunctive subjects such as here, the verb should agree with the closer subject in number—and, where necessary, also person: Either your mother or I am coming to pick you up after the play. Sometimes people find these formulations uncomfortable, however, and so reword them to avoid the issue.

@grasshopper Closing the question doesn't delete it, nor does it remove the answer.  It merely blocks additional answers.

No, you can't use can like that in English.
This is because can is a "defective" verb. Specifically, it has no infinitive or continuous forms, so it can't be preceded by the infinitive marker to or followed by -ing. You have to say...

1: Having a skill means being able [to do something]
2: Having a skill means to be able [to do something]

Note that it's more natural to repeat the initial verb form, as in #1 above, but there's nothing inherently "ungrammatical" about...

3: To have a skill means to be able [to do something]
4: To have a skill means being able [to do something]


Thanks Fumble Fingers for introducing me to the term "defective verb."

You can look up more details. Offhand I don't know the full range (or even precise definition) of "defective verb", but without giving it any thought, I expect there are some that have an infinitive but no continuous, or vice-versa. Also some that are "defective" in other ways. But that's something you can usefully look into yourself. Closely connected are irregular verbs, the history of which can be fascinating. The long-term trend is for "irregular" verbs (usually, inherited from other languages) to become regularized over time. New irregular verb forms arise very rarely.

The word "can" is a modal verb, which means it is used to indicate possibility, ability, permission, or requests. Modal verbs are typically used in conjunction with a main verb and cannot stand alone as the main verb in a sentence.
For example:

She can swim. (Here, "can" is the modal verb indicating ability, and "swim" is the main ver

